# Json column, and turn it into a wide-form data format using R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-cleaning

```
raw_data_long <-read.csv(file = 'raw_data.csv',header=T, na.strings=c("","NA"))
raw_data_long <- raw_data_long %>% mutate(tags=ifelse(tags=="[]",NA,tags))
raw_data_long<-raw_data_long %>% dplyr::select(identifier,name,tags)%>% filter(!is.na(raw_data_long$tags))
view(raw_data_long)
```

after cleaning a bit currently, the column looks like this:

[image]

I need **tags**  column JSON data pass next identifier,name column.

[image]

Single row JSON  data structure is like this:

```
 [
   {
      id=xxxxxx,
      index=8,
      **"name=Specialty"**,
      "type=coding",
      "valuestring=null",
      "valuecoding="{
         "system=https":,
         code=3904,
         **"display=Clinical oncology"**
      }
   },
   {
      id=YYYYYY,
      index=7,
      **"name=License type",**
      "type=coding",
      "valuestring=null",
      "valuecoding="{
         "system=https":,
         "code=Free",
         **"display=Free"**
      }
   },
   {
      id=ZZZZZZ,
      index=6,
      **"name=Age group",**
      "type=coding",
      "valuestring=null",
      "valuecoding="{
         "system=https":,
         "code=Adult",
         **"display=Adult"**
      }
   },
   etc... }]
```

Below are my unsuccessful attempts:

**Method 1:**

```
#view(raw_data_long$tags)
raw_data_long1<-raw_data_long%>% as.data.frame()
for (i in seq_along(raw_data_long1)) {
  #Removing the brackets
  raw_data_long1$tags[[i]] <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", raw_data_long1$tags[[i]])

  #after cleaning adding to a datframe
  d <- data.frame( json = c(raw_data_long1$tags[[i]]),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  #mutate>converting from a string to column of nested data frames.
  #unnest> unnesting these data frames into multiple columns
 d %>% mutate(json = map(json, ~ fromJSON(.) %>% as.data.frame())) %>% unnest(json)
}
```

**Method2** :: **step1**

````
raw_data_long1<-raw_data_long%>% as.data.frame()

raw_data_long2 <-for (i in seq_along(raw_data_long1)) {
  #Removing the brackets
  return (raw_data_long1$tags[[i]] <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", raw_data_long1$tags[[i]]))
}
print(raw_data_long2)
```
````

**step2:**

```
raw_data_long1<- toJSON(raw_data_long1, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
f <- function(json){
  # transform json to list
  tmp    <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)

  # transform list to data.frame
  tmp    <- as.data.frame(tmp)

  # return
  return(tmp)
}
json_dfs <- mapply(f, raw_data_long1$tags,  SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
clean_df <- data.table::rbindlist(json_dfs)
clean_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a function with `stringr` :

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
n1<-nrow(df)
CleanTags<-function(x,p1="name=.*",p2="display=.*"){

  n<-unlist(str_extract_all(x,"id")) # get number of ids
  n<- length(n)/n1 # get number of unique ids

  x<- str_replace_all(x,"\\**","") #added to remove stars genearted based on sample data
  x<- str_replace_all(x,"\\**,","")
  x<- str_replace_all(x,'[\"]','') # remove \" frm string

  x1<-unlist(str_extract_all(x, p1)) # capture data with names
  x2<-unlist(str_extract_all(x, p2)) # capture data with display

  x1<- str_replace_all(x1,"name=","") # extract values for names
  x2<-str_replace_all(x2,"display=","") # extract values for display

  x1<- str_replace_all(x1," ","_")

  x3<-cbind(x1,x2) %>% data.frame() 

  names(x3)<- c("headers","values")
  x3$rowname<-as.character(rep(seq(1, n1, by=1), each=n)) #add rownumber to create unique identifier
  x3<-x3 %>% 
    group_by(rowname)%>% 
    tidyr::spread(headers,values) 

  return(x3)
}


CleanTag_df<- df$tags %>% CleanTags() %>% data.frame() # get clean tags

CleanTag_df

  rowname Age_group License_type           Specialty
1       1     Adult         Free   Clinical oncology
2       2   Adult_1       Free_1 Clinical oncology_1

# mapping to base data
df<- df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  left_join(CleanTag_df,by=c("rowname"="rowname")) %>%
  dplyr::select(-rowname)
```

Sample data used:

```
structure(list(tags = c("[\n   {\n      id=xxxxxx,\n      index=8,\n      **\"name=Specialty\"**,\n      \"type=coding\",\n      \"valuestring=null\",\n      \"valuecoding=\"{\n         \"system=https\":,\n         code=3904,\n         **\"display=Clinical oncology\"**\n      }\n   },\n   {\n      id=YYYYYY,\n      index=7,\n      **\"name=License type\",**\n      \"type=coding\",\n      \"valuestring=null\",\n      \"valuecoding=\"{\n         \"system=https\":,\n         \"code=Free\",\n         **\"display=Free\"**\n      }\n   },\n   {\n      id=ZZZZZZ,\n      index=6,\n      **\"name=Age group\",**\n      \"type=coding\",\n      \"valuestring=null\",\n      \"valuecoding=\"{\n         \"system=https\":,\n         \"code=Adult\",\n         **\"display=Adult\"**\n      }\n   },\n   }]", 
"[\n   {\n      id=xxxxxx,\n      index=8,\n      **\"name=Specialty\"**,\n      \"type=coding\",\n      \"valuestring=null\",\n      \"valuecoding=\"{\n         \"system=https\":,\n         code=3904,\n         **\"display=Clinical oncology_1\"**\n      }\n   },\n   {\n      id=YYYYYY,\n      index=7,\n      **\"name=License type\",**\n      \"type=coding\",\n      \"valuestring=null\",\n      \"valuecoding=\"{\n         \"system=https\":,\n         \"code=Free\",\n         **\"display=Free_1\"**\n      }\n   },\n   {\n      id=ZZZZZZ,\n      index=6,\n      **\"name=Age group\",**\n      \"type=coding\",\n      \"valuestring=null\",\n      \"valuecoding=\"{\n         \"system=https\":,\n         \"code=Adult\",\n         **\"display=Adult_1\"**\n      }\n   },\n   }]"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))
```

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "rowname", value = c("1", "1", "1", : replacement has 8100 rows, data has 1350 ` ( umm we have 1350 rows each row has [{9 blocks  }].. thank you for the  lead though :)

Comment: At which step it is happening CleanTag_df level or at mapping to base data?